# Application listing in AppExchange

Tags: appexchange

What are the steps involved in listing application on AppExchange ? Is salesforce charge any cost to list application on AppExchange ? If yes, then what will be the cost ?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'll find the answers to your questions on the [Salesforce App Exchange Developer Guide](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/howToPublish) web page. In essence, you become a partner with SF and they help you market your product. They want you to be successful. Your product does have to go through a testing & validation process and for first time partners, I believe there's a very nominal initial fee based on what I recall from a recent presentation done by the guy who created Dupe Catcher here in the DFW area. The docs should tell you all you need to know.